# Two warnings "This local variable has the same name as a global variable" and "ELSE with no matching IF"

Tags: variables, debugging, scope, conditional-statements, autohotkey

I'm getting two weird warnings.

- One is "This local variable has the same name as a global variable",
  referring to the `wx`, `wy`, `ww`, `wh`.
- Another is "`ELSE` with no matching `IF`", referring to the two `if-else` statements.

Here's the whole script.

```
#NoEnv  
#Warn  
SendMode Input  
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  

screen_scaling_factor := A_ScreenDPI/96

^p::mouse_move_win(200,300)

mouse_move_win(x,y,horizontal:="left",vertical:="top",mouse_click:=""){
    wingetpos,wx,wy,ww,wh,a
    global screen_scaling_factor
    if horizontal="left"{
        x1 := wx + x * screen_scaling_factor
    }else{
        x1 := wx + ww - x * screen_scaling_factor
    }
    if vertical="top"{
        y1 := wy + y * screen_scaling_factor
    }else{
        y1 := wy + wh - y * screen_scaling_factor
    }
    DllCall("SetCursorPos", int, x1, int, y1)       
}
```

- When I add `local` as the first line of the function to enable the "force-local mode", however, the first warning disappears.
- When I add a parentheses to the if condition or remove the curly braces following it, as shown below, the second warning disappears.

```
if (horizontal="left"){
    x1 := wx + x * screen_scaling_factor
}else{
    x1 := wx + ww - x * screen_scaling_factor
}
```

or

```
if horizontal="left"
    x1 := wx + x * screen_scaling_factor
else
    x1 := wx + ww - x * screen_scaling_factor
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the legacy style if statement (please don't) you can't start your braces from the same line as the if statement. You'd have to drop the starting brace `{` down one line.

But please just use the modern expression style if-statement like so:

```
mouse_move_win(x,y,horizontal:="left",vertical:="top",mouse_click:=""){
    wingetpos,wx,wy,ww,wh,a
    global screen_scaling_factor
    if (horizontal="left"){
        x1 := wx + x * screen_scaling_factor
    }else{
        x1 := wx + ww - x * screen_scaling_factor
    }
    if (vertical="top"){
        y1 := wy + y * screen_scaling_factor
    }else{
        y1 := wy + wh - y * screen_scaling_factor
    }
    DllCall("SetCursorPos", int, x1, int, y1)       
}
```

Also, personally I'd call that brace style disgusting, but of course it's just personal preference haha.
But just in case you didn't know, you can omit braces from one liner if/else statements:

```
mouse_move_win(x,y,horizontal:="left",vertical:="top",mouse_click:="")
{
    wingetpos,wx,wy,ww,wh,a
    global screen_scaling_factor
    if (horizontal="left")
        x1 := wx + x * screen_scaling_factor
    else
        x1 := wx + ww - x * screen_scaling_factor
    if (vertical="top")
        y1 := wy + y * screen_scaling_factor
    else
        y1 := wy + wh - y * screen_scaling_factor
    DllCall("SetCursorPos", int, x1, int, y1)       
}
```

---

EDIT: oh seems you edited your post. I started typing this before you edited it, but then I had to go do something.
Anyway, my answer should answer your questions.

Comment: The first paragraph doesn't seem to come to an end. Do you mean that I use expression style in function parameters, so I'd better not using legacy style within that function? BTW, do you have any idea on the first error message?

Comment: I don't know what I was typing there, had to have been some mistake, I edited out the last sentence now. And I'm pretty sure the first error just came from the code being interpreted wrong because of the braces were wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use mouse_move`_win`(200, 300) instead of mouse_move(200,300)

When you define horizontal:="left", it means Left is its default value, meaning if no value is supplied it assumes it's left. So

if horizontal=left

is unnecessary.

So I guess your code should be other way around with the if and else combos.

```
^p::mouse_move_win(200, 300)

mouse_move_win(x, y, horizontal:="left", vertical:="top", mouse_click:="") {
    wingetpos,wx,wy,ww,wh,a
    global screen_scaling_factor
    if horizontal=right
        x1 := wx + ww - x * screen_scaling_factor
    else
        x1 := wx + x * screen_scaling_factor
    if vertical=bottom
        y1 := wy + wh - y * screen_scaling_factor
    else
        y1 := wy + y * screen_scaling_factor
    DllCall("SetCursorPos", int, x1, int, y1)
}
```

This worked perfectly for me

Comment: what's mouse_click:="" for? Just Out of Curiosity...

Comment: It seems I forgot to paste the last line of the code, which implemented a "mouse clicking" action when that argument is set to true.

Comment: The `mouse_move(200,300)` is a typo. And yes, a function very similar to this, only without declaring `local` in the first line, works pretty well, while this doesn't, which why it puzzles me. @user14349190